# how to detect printer available using wifi in android

Tags: android

I want to show list of printer available in WiFi range and then when user select the printer from available printer list and print the text file . I have done lot of searching but didn't find the solution and i don't want to use Google cloud.so any help must be appreciated.

Comment: You means connection between android and printer directly? then It's hard to make it. I'm not sure about it. If you have any evidence about it. please share to me.

Comment: yes i want exactly this, this work has been done in printer-share app in Google market.

Comment: If you are talking about windows shared printers inside the network you would have to implement that network functionality. if youre talking about apple protocol shared printers it would be a different functionality. and if youre talking about network printers then it would be different again. You would have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I am working on same problem. Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Google Cloud is the only software that can handle your request, only if you have a HP Printer, you can use Apple's AirPrint.